# GnuCash/Finance::Quote not working for Vanguard funds

Tags: gnucash, vanguard, yahoo-finance

I have money in some Vanguard funds (VTSAX and VTTSX), and track my money locally in GnuCash. Some time ago, I had it set up to automatically update the prices of these funds (Price Editor → Get Quotes). The last time this definitely worked was March of 2017. More recent attempts to autofetch prices have resulted in "There was an unknown error while retrieving the price quotes". I've finally gotten fed up with manual input and want to get the automatics working again. I already found [this QA](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87192/how-to-fix-financequote-to-pull-quotes-in-gnucash) saying that the Yahoo Finance API is gone, but these securities are set up with the single quote source "Vanguard", not any of the Yahoo sources. Would the fix be the same as for the Yahoo issue, or is this unrelated?

Comment: This question has already been answered: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87192/how-to-fix-financequote-to-pull-quotes-in-gnucash

Comment: That is there thing I specifically mentioned regarding Yahoo. Since the source I was using is not Yahoo, I don't know whether it is relevant, or whether a Yahoo-replacement would work.